# How can I integrate Pure CSS framework with a tool such as Figma

Tags: pure-css

I would like to use a light CSS framework like Pure CSS, but also combine its use with a user-friendly design tool like Figma. How can I do this with Figma or any other tool?

Comment: Surely it would be done by simply pointing your site's `<link rel>` to your copy of Pure CSS?

Comment: Thanks Obsedian.  Does your approach mean I do not use https://www.figma.com/ tool.  If I like to use that, how can I integrate Pure-CSS into the tool?  Maybe I am not understanding your response correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Dreamweaver is best tool. You can live preview of changes for the front end. Also it allows to design and code too. Figma can only design but can see CSS codes according to the your designs. [For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlT4d.jpg) This is the link to download Dreamweaver. [Go through Dreamweaver](https://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)